# Lexsorting Pandas Multi-Index with datetime index and string index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, datetimeindex

I have created a number of dataframes, all with varied overlapping datetime indexes. I then append them to each other, and append a second index, the "name" column.

i try to get a slice of the dataframe by the entry in name, but it says it is not lexsorted. When i try to lexsort, it throws an error on the string in the name column, saying it is not a date...

```
df0 = pd.read_csv("file.csv", index_col='date', parse_dates=True)
df1 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", index_col='date', parse_dates=True)

stack = pd.concat([df0, df1] ,axis=0)
stack.set_index('name', append=True,inplace=True)

print(stack.loc[datetime(2015,5,1)])
print(stack.loc['AAA'])
```

The .loc on date works and returns all names and values for the given date, but the .loc on the string, in the second index returns
`UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex slicing requires the index to be lexsorted: slicing on levels [0], lexsort depth 0'`

When I try to sort, based on what ive read here, using `stack.sort_index(inplace=True)` I get the error `ValueError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: AAA`

the dataframe stack looks like this:

```
date       name       value
1/1/15     AAA         1
...        ...         ...
12/1/15    AAA         9
1/1/15     BBB         6
...        ...         ...
12/1/15    BBB         3
```

and i would like to be able to return all dates and values for AAA. I understand i can just keep it as a single index, and do groupby or filter, but I thought this was the purpose of the multiindex?

*Edited again to clarify - I would like to know how to lexsort the second index. I am not sure why pandas is expecting it to also be a datetimeindex, which I think is what it is implying.*

edited to add stack.head(), but its as i represented above.

```
                    value         
date       name
2015-01-02 AAA     164.71  
2015-01-05 AAA     163.00  
2015-01-06 AAA     160.82  
2015-01-07 AAA     159.90  
2015-01-08 AAA     160.65
```

*Edit3: When i sort the level name using `stack.sort_index(level = [1], inplace=True,axis=0)`*

*I get:
`pandas.errors.UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex slicing requires the index to be lexsorted: slicing on levels [0], lexsort depth 0`*

Comment: can you provide a sample of `stack`? `stack.head(10).to_dict()`, or a DataFrame constructor with a minimal example.

Comment: which pandas version do you have? the sorting works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for a cross-section ([`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)):

```
df.xs('AAA', level='name', drop_level=False)
```

example:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'value': {(Timestamp('2015-01-02 00:00:00'), 'AAA'): 164.71,
                              (Timestamp('2015-01-05 00:00:00'), 'AAA'): 163.0,
                              (Timestamp('2015-01-06 00:00:00'), 'AAA'): 160.82,
                              (Timestamp('2015-01-02 00:00:00'), 'BBB'): 159.9,
                              (Timestamp('2015-01-05 00:00:00'), 'BBB'): 160.65}})
        .rename_axis(['date', 'name'])
        .sort_index(level=1)
     )

df.xs('AAA', level='name', drop_level=False)

                  value
date       name        
2015-01-02 AAA   164.71
2015-01-05 AAA   163.00
2015-01-06 AAA   160.82
```

Alternatively, using [`IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, 'AAA'], :]
```

Comment: Do you know how to get my second index 'name' to be lexsorted?

Comment: @FredSmith `df.sort_index(level=[0,1])` or `df.sort_index(level=[1,0])` depending on which major you want

Answer (score 1):

I dont like this solution but after lots of tinkering I arrived at :

`stack.loc[(slice(None),'AAA'),:]`

If there is another way than this or mozway's solution please reply.

Edit -- all sorts of issues in what I had done ---
`Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: AAA` was because I was trying to lookup AAA without specifying in anyway that it was index level [1]. Had nothing to do with the sort. The sort worked just fine.

In retrospect, I guess the solution I was hoping for was
`stack.loc[:,'AAA']`
but thats just not the way it is. Already lost too many hours on this, hope it saves someone else the effort. Thanks Mozway!

Comment: why don't you like it? You can also use IndexSlice (see update)